# Unique Representation of Elements in the Complex Circle Group

Tags: complex-analysis

In a few weeks I'll have my first course in Complex Analysis and right now I'm doing some preparation.
I found the following exercise and I'm struggling to get the right solution:

For $z\in { S }^{ 1 }\setminus \left\{ -1 \right\} $ and ${ S }^{ 1 }:=\left\{ z\in\Bbb C:\left| z \right| =1 \right\} $

I want to prove that every $z\in { S }^{ 1 }\setminus \left\{ -1 \right\} $ can be uniquely written in the form

$$z=\frac { 1+i\lambda  }{ 1-i\lambda  } =\frac { 1-{ \lambda  }^{ 2 } }{ 1+{ \lambda  }^{ 2 } } +\frac { 2\lambda  }{ 1+{ \lambda  }^{ 2 } } i$$

($\lambda \in\Bbb R$).
I think I'm lacking the right intuition could someone help, please.

Comment: Have you tried solving for $\lambda?$

Comment: yes but i couldn't derive any information, but maybe my geometry was wrong

Comment: It would help if you showed us your work, so we could address the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Yes sorry, i did spent some more thoughts on the problem and npticed a mistake in my represention of Lambda and i'm only left with one question. If i have solved for Lambda is it suffiecent to now show that lambda is equal to his complexe conjugated to proof that lambda is real and than proof it's uniquness to complete the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}z=\frac{1+i\lambda}{1-i\lambda}&\iff z-i\lambda z=1+i\lambda\\&\iff z-1=\lambda i(z+1)\\&\iff\lambda=i\frac{1-z}{1+z}\\&\iff\lambda=i\frac{(1-z)(1+\overline z)}{|1+z|^2}=\frac{2\operatorname{Im}z}{|1+z|^2}\in\mathbb R.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For any $z\in \mathbb S^1$ there is a unique $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ such that

$$z = e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\cdot \sin(\theta).$$